# Diffence between "select count(null)" and "select count(1)"

Tags: mysql

In MySQL

```
Select 1 from mytable
```

and

```
select null from mytable
```

both return the same number of rows. While `select count(1) from mytable` returns the rowcount and `select count(null) from mytable` always returns 0. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COUNT` returns the number of non-NULL values, that's why it returns 0 for NULL.

Comment: Thanks. here is the documentation link i found for this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count